# How do sigfig, futureadvisor, wikinvest connect to broker accounts (e.g. fidelity, etrade)? Is there an api?

Tags: finance

Sigfig, futureadvisor, wikinvest and other newer websites let you input your username/pwd and connect to your brokerage account to retrieve trades, holdings, cost basis, etc.  Does each brokerage have its own api? Is there a broad api? Quicken seems to do this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to work for SigFig / Wikinvest.  They're the same company, but all portfolio-sync capabilities are transitioning to SigFig.

Most brokerages have their own API set up to deliver XML for your account data using the OFX (or QFX) standard and various authorization protocols.  A lot of this infrastructure was originally driven by Quicken's need to aggregate account data across platforms, but the APIs remain for everyone.

Many financial sites (Mint.com, for example, before they were bought out by Intuit) make use of a third-party platform such as Yodlee or ByAllAccounts to support working with all of these brokerage APIs, however, at SigFig/Wikinvest we built our own platform to avoid that dependency.  Documentation and even the publicity of many of these APIs are non-existent so it took months and years of research to get it working correctly.  Cleansing the data across all platforms was another months/years effort and one that isn't necessarily provided by third-party providers.  Finally, the security required to be able to tap into any of these APIs is an entirely different subject that I'll not get into any detail here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the co-founder of FutureAdvisor. We use Yodlee to connect and sync customer investment information from brokerages.

If you're thinking about doing this, there are several other solutions in addition to Yodlee:

1. Direct using OFX: The Open Financial Exchange (OFX) protocol can be used to access data directly from brokerages. Depending on your need, you'll have to roll your own OFX client here. For frequent connectivity scenarios, keep in mind you may be rate-limited on your access depending on the brokerage. Docs: http://www.ofx.net/
2. Intuit Data Aggregation: Intuit has their own data aggregation service and it's launching in the fall. Mint switched to this after being acquired by Intuit: http://developer.intuit.com/agg-cat/
3. CashEdge: Does data aggregation and sync from brokerages much like Yodlee and Intuit.
4. ByAllAccounts: We have not looked at this in enough detail but I understand that traditional investment advisors and wealth managers tend to use this for their client management systems. So the service handles this scenario well.

This is by no means a comprehensive list but probably a good short-list to start with depending on your core scenario or need.